# VBA 'Argument Not Optional' Error

Tags: vba, excel

So I have this code to loop through selected items in a listbox and add them to a collection. For some reason it is throwing the compile error "Argument Not Optional" on the commented out line that is trying to add the selected item to the Collection.

However, the line adding "test" works fine.

I know this is an optional argument because it even gives me Intellisense popup to use "Add". So I'm pretty confused.

```
    If optPaste = True Then
        'Paste Code
    Else
        'Read In Selection
            Dim tempArray As Variant
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim colSelected As Collection
            Set colSelected = New Collection
            colSelected.Add ("test")

                For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
                    If Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
                        tempArray = Split(Me.ListBox1.List(i), " - ")
                       ' colSelected.Add = tempArray(1)
                    End If
                Next i
                MsgBox (colSelected(1))
    End If
```

Comment: remove the `=` from that line

Comment: @ScottCraner *facepalm* thank you

Comment: `If optPaste = True Then` can be reduced to `If optPaste Then` since the test expression argument for the `If` statement is itself testing whether the supplied expression evaluates to `True`.